# Space of solutions to xf=0 (distributions)

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that all the solutions to $xf=0$ can be written $c\delta$.

Similar question: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656951/a-short-question-concerning-the-distributional-solution-of-xf-0) but it doesn't seem to be using the same approach- although I cannot fully understand this argument.

I do not understand how these arguments come together or result in the full solution. From knowing that $\phi(0)=0$, how do we conclude that the solutions are of this form?

The text I was reading treated this as an obvious fact and I was unable to find an explicit proof online.

What is a complete proof of this argument?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so let's just try to tear this apart methodically.

Naïvely, for $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}),$ you'd like to say that for any $\phi=(\phi-\phi(0))+\phi(0),$ because then you notice that $\phi-\phi(0)=x\psi,$ where $\psi(x)=(\phi(x)-\phi(0))/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $\psi(x)=\phi'(0)$ if $x=0$.

However, this is a decomposition into functions that do not a priori have compact support (well, they never do unless $\phi(0)$ was $0$). Hence, we need to kill things off. So let $\xi$ be a smooth function with compact support which is identically $1$ on the support of $\phi$. Then,

$$
\langle f,\phi\rangle=\langle f,\xi\phi\rangle=\langle f,\xi(\phi-\phi(0))\rangle+\langle f,\xi \phi(0)\rangle=\langle f,x\psi\xi\rangle+\phi(0)\langle f,\xi\rangle=\phi(0)\langle f,\xi\rangle
$$ 
Assume support of $\phi$ was chosen to have support in $[-K,K]$ and $\xi_K$ was chosen identically $1$ on $[-K,K]$ (this fits into the above set-up). Thus, we have shown that there exists a constant $C_K:=\langle f,\xi_K\rangle$ such that $\langle f,\phi \rangle=\phi(0)\langle f,\xi_K\rangle=\langle C_K\delta_0,\phi\rangle $ for all $\phi$ with support in $[-K,K]$. We just have to argue that all these constants are really the same.

However, if we let $K<K',$ any test-function $\phi$ with support in $[-K,K]$ also has support in $[-K',K'],$ which implies that 
$$
\langle C_K \delta_0,\phi\rangle=\langle f,\phi\rangle=\langle C_K'\delta_0,\phi\rangle,
$$
implying that the $C_K=C_K'$.

Thus, any solution is of the form $C\delta_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u \in \mathcal{D}'$ satisfy $xu=0$ and take $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$.

If $\varphi(0)=0$ then there exists $\psi \in C_c^\infty$ such that $\varphi=x\psi,$ so 
$\langle u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, x\psi \rangle = \langle xu, \psi \rangle = \langle 0, \psi \rangle = 0.$

If $\varphi(0)\neq0,$ take $\rho \in C_c^\infty$ such that $\rho(0)=1$ and let $\hat{\varphi} = \varphi - \varphi(0)\rho.$ Then $\hat{\varphi}(0)=0$ so $\langle u, \hat{\varphi} \rangle = 0$ by last paragraph. Thus,
$\langle u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \varphi(0)\rho \rangle = \langle u, \rho \rangle \varphi(0) = C\langle \delta, \varphi \rangle,$
where $C = \langle u, \rho \rangle.$